# Colour into range rows issue

Tags: excel, vba, row

[image: This is the incorrect lines]

[image: This is the correct way it should be]

I created a VBA code to fill in color to rows above where there is text in Column C, which works mostly. But it seems to be missing some rows, & filling in a couple of places on the incorrect row.
For example; it misses out row 22, 92 & 102. And then it fills in row 26, rather than 27.
Have attached the code & function below:

```
Private Sub Add_Break_Lines_Click()
Dim cmd As ComboBox
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job Card Master")
Set cmb = Me.Add_Break_Lines

LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

ws.Range("P13:P299").ClearContents

Select Case CMB.Value

      Case ("Break Lines 1 Page Job Card")
                    colorAbove ws.Range("A13:Q" & LastRow)
                    
      Case ("Break Lines 2 Page Job Card")
                    colorAbove ws.Range("A13:Q61")
                    colorAbove ws.Range("A66:Q" & LastRow)
                    
      Case ("Break Lines 3 Page Job Card")
                    colorAbove ws.Range("A13:Q61")
                    colorAbove ws.Range("A66:Q122")
                    colorAbove ws.Range("A127:Q" & LastRow)
                    
       Case ("Break Lines 4 Page Job Card")
                    colorAbove ws.Range("A13:Q61")
                    colorAbove ws.Range("A66:Q122")
                    colorAbove ws.Range("A127:Q183")
                    colorAbove ws.Range("A188:Q" & LastRow)
                    
       Case ("Break Lines 5 Page Job Card")
                    colorAbove ws.Range("A13:Q61")
                    colorAbove ws.Range("A66:Q122")
                    colorAbove ws.Range("A127:Q183")
                    colorAbove ws.Range("A188:Q244")
                    colorAbove ws.Range("A249:Q" & LastRow)
End Select

Me.Add_Break_Lines.Text = "Add Break Lines"

      End Sub

      Sub colorAbove(rng As Range)

        Dim brg As Range
        Dim rrg As Range
        Dim EmptyRowNum As Long
        Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    Set rrg = rng.Rows(i)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rrg) = 0 Then
        EmptyRowNum = EmptyRowNum + 1
    End If
    If EmptyRowNum = 2 Then
        EmptyRowNum = 0
        If brg Is Nothing Then
            Set brg = rrg
        Else
            Set brg = Union(brg, rrg)
        End If
    End If
Next i

If Not brg Is Nothing Then
    brg.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
End If

   End Sub
```

Comment: In fact, what do you want doing? To color the row above the empty one? To color the row is the second one being empty?

Comment: The row above all filled-in cells in column C. To color the row below the empty rows.

Comment: A couple of screenshots (expected/what you actually get) would really help here.

Comment: Still  not cler from more points of view... If the row below an empty row should be colored, no need of all the function code. I would be enough something like : `If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng.Rows(i)) = 0 Then Set rrg = rng.Rows(i + 1)`. Then, there is no any condition regarding "all filled-in cells in column C". I do not understand what is to be done, sorry...

Comment: @FaneDuru - Col C part refers to `LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row` I think

Comment: @Tim Williams: Maybe... But he was trying to answer my above questions and I cannot understand why he mentioned this aspect. It is not possible to understand what he needs, I think. His function looks to make a range from empty rows. Only the second occurrence.

Comment: @FaneDuru - agree it's unclear what the intended result of the code should be.

Comment: I have added screenshots to make it clear. The top one is wrong the bottom image is correct.

Comment: Please can somebody help with this question today

Comment: Please can somebody help with this question today